# Terraform trying to refresh a non existing state

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I recently wanted to destroy completely my infrastructure. Currently Terraform do not deliver enough feature for this process, so I did theses steps :

- Running `terraform destroy`
- Destroying the resources not destroy
- Removing the state

The command : `terraform state list` returns me :

```
No state file was found!
```

At this point everything is fine, but the problem is I want to apply my Terraform project (`terraform apply`).

But it's trying to refresh my resources :

```
module.terrakube.module.monitoring.data.helm_repository.loki: Refreshing state...
module.lexon-website-b2c.data.kubernetes_service.lexon-b2c: Refreshing state...
module.terrakube.module.cluster.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Refreshing state...
And more...
```

It shouldn't try to refresh resources because they do not exist and it fails because it tries to access to the Kubernetes Cluster which do not and should not exist.

I also remove the file `terraform.tfstate` in `.terraform` just in case, but the issue is still here.

Why is Terraform trying to refresh a non existing state ?

Comment: Is there a .terraform dir under the current dir? If so, please try after `mv .terraform .terraform_old`

Comment: Yes there is a `.terraform` dir but only contains my modules, plugins and providers. I already removed files related to the state `.terraform/terraform.tfstate`. I will not remove this folder cause it contains providers rebuilt by my own with fixes.